# Unable to simulate click to load window by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

Page: http://csgo.exchange/

I am trying to simulate a click on the "Item Float" option from the "Calculator" menu via jQuery but it's not loading the desired window.

My code:

```
var itemfloat = $('li').find('a[href$="#item/market"]');
itemfloat.click();
```

What's ridiculous is that itemfloat.remove(); works but not itemfloat.click();

**IMPORTANT:** The scripts runs as intended when pasted in the console but not when run as a content script in a Chrome Extension..

Comment: It does work for me...Paste these lines in console and test..

Comment: True! It does! I'm surprised. I'm running the script through a Chrome Extension content script and it's not working.

Comment: is `jQ` included ?

Comment: Yes, it's loaded as a content script.

Comment: Dont provide additional information in comments; always edit/update your question instead. Not everybody will take the time to dive through all the comments; so that limits your chance of getting good answers.

Comment: Try adding `eq()` at the end of selector. I mean like this `$('li').find('a[href$="#item/market"]').eq(0)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Triggering a click event from content script - chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819344/triggering-a-click-event-from-content-script-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 0):

it work, but you can simplify it for better code reading

```
$('li').find('a[href$="#item/market"]').click();
```

Comment: What is `$('li').find('a[href$="#item/market"]')` is used many times in the code ?

Comment: True, but for a single time use, is better and more clearly, easy to understand the code for the next developer that  comes.

Comment: @RaduLozovanu, for `triggering` others DOM `click`, refer this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/zeuenokm/).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I needed at:[Triggering a click event from content script - chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819344/triggering-a-click-event-from-content-script-chrome-extension)

Working code:

```
$('li').find('a[href$="#item/market"]')[0].click();
```