# Triggering a click event from chrome extensions content script - Part II

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm having serious trouble doing something very simple.  I'd like to use a chrome extension content script to trigger the video in the following url to play:

http://sports24.club/watch?id=espn2

The following code triggers that video in the dev console:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('player-poster')[0].click();
```

Or

```
$('.player-poster')[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click"));
```

Or

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].play();
```

I've tried some other variations, including using the "trigger" method.  They also work.

However, when placed in a content script, every variation simply throws an *Uncaught (in promise) DOMException*.

I've looked around, and the best advice I received was from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819344/triggering-a-click-event-from-content-script-chrome-extension) SO question.  But even that didn't work.

I would really love if any of you could explain:

1. Why is this happening?  I get that content scripts live in their own little world, but why would that cause a .click() method to not work?
2. How do I get around that and make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: When things work in a console but don't in a content script, assuming the node is present at the time the content script runs, the solution is usually to put the code into a [page-level script element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).

Comment: Hi @wOxxOm!  I was hoping you'd respond (I've seen your responses in other posts).  I actually had tried the following earlier, and that also didn't work.  Is this  what you meant by a page-level script element?

$("<script>setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('ads').style.display = 'none';document.getElementsByTagName(\"video\")[0].play();}, 3000);</" + "script>").appendTo(document.body);

Comment: I'm not sure jQuery-added script actually runs. Add a console.log to verify or use vanilla js.

Comment: So here's the strange part:  I added the log, and then reloaded the extension.  When I reloaded the page, I opened up the dev console at the same time.  Suddenly the video played, and the log also showed up in the dev console.  However, when I reload the page without opening the dev console, the video does not play.  When I open the dev console, the log does show, however.  If I reload the page with the dev console already open, the video does not play, but the log shows. 

What the heck...?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?