# Chrome Extension - Trigger events on content_scripts using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, jquery-events

I wrote a Chrome Extension that automatically fills some registration forms. There are some select fields that need to be triggered on "**change**" event in order to start some Ajax calls.

First I use JQuery attr or val to change the value of the select field, and than I use **.trigger** to invoke the "change" event, but this last one doesn't work.

Example:

> I want to select the option that contains the word "London" and invoke
>   the change element in order to start some operations of the native
>   code that have some listeners on "change" event

```
jQuery("#SelectElement option:contains('London')").attr("selected", "selected"); 
jQuery("#SelectElement").trigger("change"); <--- not works
```

I tried also:

```
jQuery("#SelectElement option:containt('London')").attr("selected", "selected").change();
```

But if I try this code on **console**, it works.

Suggestions?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152932/chrome-extension-how-to-send-keydown-event-to-pages-input

Comment: Use the CustomEvent constructor, `var event = new CustomEvent('change');`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and as far as I know it's because of something called framework event listeners. that you cannot trigger from your code by jquery! but the solution is trigger the event this way:

`$(selector)[0].dispatchEvent(new Event("eventName"))`

Answer (score 3):

In my case,

```
var event = new CustomEvent('change');
```

did not work.

I had to initialize the event like this:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("keyup", true, true);
```

First arg 'bubbles' should be true so the event should bubble up through the event chain.

```
event.initEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable);
```

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent