# Simulating the "change()" event via extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I develop extensions which adds js code to a third-party service and automatically fills out a form for a client. On the form there is an `input` into which you enter the text, and when the "change" event is sent, it sends a request to the server and displays the matches.

The code for automation works if you execute it in the console.

```
    $(select).val('text');
    $(select).change();
```

When adding `change()` to the site through extensions, it fails.

There is speculation that this is a browser restriction for extensions.
If someone came up with an imitation of the `change()` event through **extensions**, please tell me how to solve this.

Comment: From what I read, the problem could be jQuery.  Could you please try `$('select')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event("change"))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome Extension - Trigger events on content\_scripts using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094387/chrome-extension-trigger-events-on-content-scripts-using-jquery)