# HTML5 Video Auto Click Pause on load jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I am creating a Chrome Extension which pauses the video on YouTube on load. At the moment when you click a video on YouTube it will automatically play, however I would like to pause it instead. I have found the element for the play button and at the moment I have made script, however it isn't working. Is it possible to automatically click something using jQuery?

Script:

```
$(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
   $(".ytp-button-play").trigger("click");
});
```

Also, the element for the video itself is `#movie_player` and I have tried the .load() method for that element but it isn't working either.

Here is the Inspect Element:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated :) Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery code on Chrome Extension doesnt work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398550/jquery-code-on-chrome-extension-doesnt-work)

Comment: Or alternatively, this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17152932/934239